# How do I tint an svg in processing and preserve brightness?

Tags: svg, processing

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, so I hope somebody can help.

I need to load in svg files that have multiple values of gray within them and tint them with colors. So for example, say the svg file is an image of a rock and has 4 values of gray. I need to be able to display the rock as red and keep the differences between values in the different child shapes. In other words, I would like it to work just like PImage.tint().

I see there are tint() and setTint() methods to PShape but I can't seem to get them to work. I also though about recursing through the child shapes and reading each color individually and recoloring appropriately, but I couldn't even figure out how to read the color out in a way I understand.

Help, anyone?

Comment: When I read the docs - tint() is a PImage method, not a PShape method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it as an `<img>` you can use the CSS filter property with hue-rotate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate

Or you add the svg directly to the html and add classes to your elements. Then you could change the colors in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Actually this is in the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a flat colour then you could use the alpha value in RGB colour value. See 'color transparency' in the following link: https://processing.org/tutorials/color/

The fill value is fill(red, green, blue, transparency)

I hope this helps. If you want to share code and have a reason for using PImage I'd be happy to have a look.